# How return multi table(of T) by vb.net function

Tags: vb.net, linq

I use a linQ Model for my SQL database, and I need to make a function to insert data into every table.

```
Dim mydata as object = myArray (1)
Dim Indx as integer=1
Call InsertData (indx)
...

sub InsertData (Indx as integer)
    With myFunction(Indx)       '_Context.table1s
             .InsertOnSubmit(myArray(Indx))

    End With
    _context.SubmitChanges()
End Sub

Function myFunction(i as integer)
   select case i
      case 1 :return _Context.table1s
      case 2:return _Context.table2s
      case 3: return _Context.table3s  
      ...
   End Select   
End function

Function myArray (I as integer)
     Select case I
        Case 1  : 
            Dim y as table (of table1)
             ' ... y be set
            return y
        Case 2
            Dim y2 as table (of table2)
            ....
            Return y2
            ...
     End Select
End Function
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a base type (other than `Object` shared between `table1s`, `table2s`, and `table3s`?  What's the purpose of a function that can return several unrelated types?

Comment: Dim mydata as object